# Perf command not support energy when passing process ID

Tags: performance, x86-64, perf, energy

I want to attach perf to a process and measure the package energy. As you can see below, the example shows that `power/energy-pkg/` works fine.

```
$ perf stat -a -e power/energy-pkg/ -- sleep 1

 Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

              1,71 Joules power/energy-pkg/

       1,019749321 seconds time elapsed
```

The C code gets the PID at the beginning and stops until a SIGCONT is received. With the following commands, I launch the program in background and grab the PID. Then I continue the execution and run perf with the PID.

```
$ ./app &
$ PID=`pidof app`
$ kill -SIGCONT $PID
$ perf stat -a -e power/energy-pkg -p $PID
   Performance counter stats for process id '2590':

    <not supported> Joules power/energy-pkg/

      34,002655205 seconds time elapsed
```

As you can see the energy number is invalid. Any idea about this behavior?

Comment: AFAIK, not all platform/processors support it and even when this is supported, the current support is generally pretty bad. I never succeed to get realistic results with software-based energy metrics. I think the only reliable way to measure energy consumption is to measure it physically with electronic instruments (you can sometimes get a factor of 10 between the two and you cannot just estimate the real consumption with a linear factor in practice).

Comment: Does `-p` override `-a`?  The output says "Performance counter stats **for process id ...**".  If power/energy is only available per-package, not per-core, it wouldn't be fully meaningful to measure that for just one process since other tasks on other cores (even the a logical core sharing this physical core) would be part of that count.  It could be somewhat meaningful to only record energy usage while any thread of this process was active on any core, but not while it was sleeping, but IDK if `perf` (or the underlying HW counters) are able to do that.

Comment: I agree with you that `-p` maybe overrides `-a`. However, your argument can also be applied to `sleep` command. That command is a process, too. But it works.  I don't know if that is a bug or there is a logic behind that.